# Conversion error with NULL column and SELECT INTO

Tags: sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I'm experimenting with temporary tables and running into a problem.

Here's some super-simplified code of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
IF(Object_ID('tempdb..#TempTroubleTable') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #TempTroubleTable

select 'Hello' as Greeting,
    NULL as Name
into #TempTroubleTable

update #TempTroubleTable
set Name = 'Monkey'
WHERE Greeting = 'Hello'


select * from #TempTroubleTable
```

Upon attempting the update statement, I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Monkey' to data type int.

I can understand why the temp table might not expect me to fill that column with varchars, but why does it assume int? Is there a way I can prime the column to expect varchar(max) but still initialize it with NULLs?

Comment: `NULL` defaults to `INT`. You can see this by `EXEC tempdb..sp_help '#TempTroubleTable';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast null to the datatype because by default its an int

```
Select 'hello' as greeting,
            Cast (null as varchar (32)) as name
Into #temp
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't realize that you could cast a null as something else. Thanks!